# Performance of objects with many relationship and formula fields?

Tags: governorlimits, limits

I have the need to create a denormalized, flattened view of multiple sobjects in Salesforce.com. In numbers this means 20 Lookup fields, around 100 text formula fields to extract data from those relationships and around 100 integer fields.

With that I still stay under the limits but how will this affect performance when I have 1 million or more records of that type?

Any good or bad experience on that would be highly appreciated?

Just in case you might ask: I am doing this denormalisation to reduce ten's of millions of rows with a few fields in favor of few millions with many fields. As every object record in Salesforce is just 2Kb in size and storage is so expensive that seems to be a thinkable improvement. Isn't it?!

Comment: You sure you're under limits. By my reckoning, you'll run out of cross-object formulas after the first 10 lookup fields. The limit isn't on the number of objects, but rather on the number of *relationships* you traverse.  I'll wait for someone else to come up with an answer on the big data performance question. :-) Also, by stating "every object is 2kb", I suspect you mean to state every *record*.

Comment: Peter, is there a limit on cross-object formula fields per objects? I could not find anything about that?!

Comment: From the docs: "Salesforce allows a maximum of ten unique relationships per object in cross-object formulas." Found on this page: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_on_building_formulas.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Is this a one-time deal, or something you'll run on a regular basis?  If one-time, it might be easiest to export data, process it on a PC with a Python script, and then re-import it to your org.

Answer (score 1):

The formula stuff will take time to evaluate on every request, so be careful with mass exports, etc as this will take time to run.  There is a good article on formulas and indexing in the recent Engineering blog on developer.force.com (http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/02/force-com-soql-best-practices-nulls-and-formula-fields.html).